# getting the full file path in Firefox

Tags: c#, filepath

I am using **ASP .Net MVC 4.0, vs10**

in one of my buttons click event, iam getting company name like this :

```
if (Request.Form["NAMEbtnImport"].Length > 0)
            {
                if (Request.Form["NAMEbtnUpload"].Length > 0 && Request.Form["NAMEtxtCompany"].Length > 0 )
                {
                    Session["CompanyName"] = Request.Form["NAMEtxtCompany"].ToString();
                    var x = collection.GetValue("NAMEbtnUpload"); 
                    filePath = x.AttemptedValue.ToString();
                    filePath = Request.Form["NAMEbtnUpload"];
                    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);                                        //var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads"), filePath);
                    if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
                    {
                        System.IO.File.Copy(filePath, Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + fileName));
                    }
                    companyName = Request.Form["NAMEtxtCompany"].ToString();
                    newFilePath = "Uploads/" + fileName;
                    ViewBag.CompanyName = companyName;
                }
```

This is my html : **[EDIT]**

```
<input type="file" value="Upload" id="IDbtnUpload" name="NAMEbtnUpload"/>
```

this is working fine in IE. filepath is full. but in Firefox, only the filename is recieving. Both collection and request.form outputs same data.

what is the problem here? Sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 2):

Internet Explorer sends the full file path to the server; Firefox doesn't.

This is a security decision by the browser authors; there's nothing you can do about it.

Furthermore, it looks like you're using `File.Copy` to try to copy the source uploaded file to somewhere on the server. This is only made for copying *local* files - it won't work if the browser isn't running on the server!

You need to use something like

```
<asp:FileUpload  runat="server" ID="fuSample" />
```

in your `aspx` file and

```
if (fuSample.HasFile)
{
    fuSample.SaveAs(
        Server.MapPathMapPath("~/Uploads/" + fuSample.FileName));
}
```

in your codebehind.

Edit: If you're stuck with a vanilla `<input type="file" id="someID" ... />`, try

```
var file = this.Context.Request.Files["someID"];
if (file != null)
    file.SaveAs(Server.MapPathMapPath("~/Uploads/" + file.FileName));
```

Comment: i am using razor view. so I have used <input type="file" />. see my edit portion. How could i solve this?

Comment: @user1865670 I'm not 100% certain, but I've edited into my answer what the `FileUpload` seems to be donig behind the scenes.

Comment: ERROR showing --> cannot implicitly convert postedFileBaase to PostedFile?

Comment: @user1865670 use HttpPostedFileBase instead of HttpPostedFile. See the code in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Are you expecting to access the full filepath on the client machine? You shouldn't be able to do this, and should have no need to either.

Browsers allowing this would be a security risk.

Apologies in advance if I have misunderstood what you're trying to do!

EDIT: To handle a file upload in MVC you can use HttpPostedFileBase in your action. Something like this:

```
<input type="file" name="file">
```

and

```
//POST FORM

        public ActionResult form_Post(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {

              if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                  file.SaveAs(mySavePath);
                 }
         }
```

EDIT: and some more code on file saving for your latest comment:

```
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/myupload/path/"), fileName);

                if (!System.IO.File.Exists(path))
                {
                    file.SaveAs(path);
                }
```

Comment: @user1865670 try HttpPostedFileBase as demonstrated here.

Comment: "save path is not rooted". What does it mean?

Comment: @user1865670 see latest edit for some sample code saving file to server.